# <a> tag not wrapping text completely when generated by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with a jQuery function that appends tags, but it only occurs about 40% of the time.  My  tags are not completely wrapping my text.

Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('/ycomb', function(data){ // gets the JSON info
      for(var i = 0; i<30;i++){
          $("<li><p><a href=" + data[i].url + ">" + data[i].title + "</a></p></li>").appendTo("#helper")
       }
});
```

Here is an example of a bad output:

```
<p>
    <a href="google.com"></a>
    "A search engine"
    </p>
```

Here is an example of a correct output:

```
<p>
    <a href="bing.com">"A search that competes against google"</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you post the data returned by the ajax request?

Comment: @Streamside probably asked for the return data as the code is valid, and the spacing is probably within the `Ajax` return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use different quotes. Try this:

```
$.getJSON('/ycomb', function(data){ // gets the JSON 
    for(var i = 0; i<30;i++){
        $('<li><p><a href="' + data[i].url + '">' + data[i].title + '</a></p></li>').appendTo('#helper');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $.getJSON('/ycomb', function(data){ // gets the JSON info
        for(var i = 0; i<30;i++){
            html = "<li><p><a href=" + data[i].url + ">" + data[i].title + "</a></p></li>";
            html.appendTo("#helper")
         }
   });
```

Luck with that

Comment: This code does not validate properly due to a syntax error after the </p>"